# LWC Pulling Object RecordTypeIds

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to get all of the record types for a specific object so I can use them to filter data in my LWC.  I import the object and use a wire to get the object info without issue.  The console.log does return the data. However, when I try to query for the specific record type at the third line, I get the error:

> portalMidOppManagementProds.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
> [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'recordTypeInfos')]

```
//get object info for Horizon Product (needed to get record types in Horizon Product Queries)
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: HORIZONPRODUCTS_OBJECT })
 hpobjectInfo;

const rtis = this.hpobjectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
console.log('here is the hpobjectdInfo ' + JSON.stringify(rtis))
const HrecType =  Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'Health');
```

I do have a record type named health that is returned in the console.log.   Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check your JSON data structure.  if recordTypeInfos is list object, you may loop through the object to get the data.

Comment: Even with a loop I get the error.  I updated the original post with the extended error.  Looks like the error is happening in the wire only when I have line 3... If I don't try to look up a value, I don't get the error.  thanks!

Comment: You're trying to access the data before it's available. I presume you're trying to access this value either in connectedCallback or renderedCallback. You have to wait for the data to be returned from the server.

Comment: Also, for future reference, when asking about LWC code, it's useful to include all the relevant parts of your class, including imports, function names, etc. In LWC, context is often important to getting the correct solution.

Comment: Sorry sfdcfox.  I update the post to include the import.  I'm unsure of why you say the data is unavailble if the console.log displays the data in the rtis variable.   The data is in a method that gets called from another wire. thanks!

Comment: My educated guess is that your code is being called 2 times; first time it fails because the data isn't available, next time it runs fine because the data has been provisioned. If the code were called only once, it would be literally impossible to both get this error and have rtis be populated, because the exception would have stopped any further execution.

Comment: As always, I appreciate your help!  I will add an if statement checking for the data first.